# Writing a recurrence in terms of a shift operator

Tags: computer-science, recurrence-relations

This is a concept that I vaguely understand, but I'd like to get an intuitive understanding of how to write a recurrence relation of the form:
$$
t_{n}-3t_{n-1}+2t_{n-2}=0
$$
subject to
$$
t_0=2,  t_1=3
$$
in terms of the shift operator $E$, in order to derive a characteristic polynomial. I already know this particular equation can be expressed as:
$$
(E^{2}-3E+2)t=0
$$
I understand that the second expression is defined by the operations done on a solution sequence $t$ such that $t_{1...n}=0$, but is there an easier way to come up with that expression that simply writing the first few terms of the sequence and moving things around?

Edit: fixed second expression (+2, not -2)

Comment: It should be $(E^2-3E+2)t=0$. You can read it straight from the recurrence: choose $n$ to make the smallest index $0$, and replace $at_k$ by $aE^k$.

Comment: Thank you!! This tip makes total sense. I just needed that little push to make the connection. You can go ahead and answer this with that strategy and I'll mark it as best answer. Especially since I may have an exam concerning this in a few hours :)

Comment: You’re welcome! I posted it as a comment simply because I wasn’t sure whether that was where you were hung up. Oh, and good luck with the exam.

Comment: Yep, I'm in an algorithms class this semester. I understood how to come up with the expression through intuition and looking at the solution sequence, but when they started giving us recurrences with fractional coefficients I knew there had to be an easier way to see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your shift equation should be $(E^2-3E+2)t=0$: you have the wrong sign on the constant term.)

You can read it straight from the recurrence: choose $n$ to make the smallest index $0$, and replace $at_k$ by $aE^k$ throughout.